# How to stringfy a POCO object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, poco

I have a really large collection of POCO objects with several sub-properties that i need to mock...

While using quick-watch, i see the entity as i wanted it to be...

What i'm looking for is sort of a extension method or a way to stringfy it so i can go to my unit test and mock it there... sort of:

```
var myPoco = new Poco {
                       //here goes whatever i get from my magic method
                      };
```

any on how to stringfy all the properties names and values of a given object so that it can be assignable?

**EDIT 1:**
I'm looking for something like:

```
    public static string StringFy(this object obj, string prefix)
    {
        string result = "";
        obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            result += prefix + "." + i.Name + " = ";
            if (i.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                result += "\"" + i.GetValue(obj) + "\";\r\n";
            }
            else
            if (i.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                result += "new Guid(\"" + i.GetValue(obj) + "\");\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                var objAux = i.GetValue(obj);
                result += (objAux == null ? "null" : objAux) + ";\r\n";
            }
        });
        return result.Replace(" = True;", " = true;").Replace(" = False;", " = false;");
    }
```

Comment: I've never actually done this before, so I'll leave it as a comment rather than an answer, but I think you could create an indexer on your class that uses reflection to set properties via string value of the property name. Look up using reflection to set values by property name, and also look up indexers if you're not familiar with what I'm talking about there.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an indexer on your class that uses reflection to set properties via string value of the property name. Here is a sample class:

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionAndIndexers
{
    class ReflectionIndexer
    {
        public string StrProp1 { get; set; }
        public string StrProp2 { get; set; }
        public int IntProp1 { get; set; }
        public int IntProp2 { get; set; }

        public object this[string s]
        {
            set
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(s, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(this, value, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then test it:

```
using System;

namespace ReflectionAndIndexers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ri = new ReflectionIndexer();
            ri["StrProp1"] = "test1";
            ri["StrProp2"] = "test2";
            ri["IntProp1"] = 1;
            ri["IntProp2"] = 2;

            Console.WriteLine(ri.StrProp1);
            Console.WriteLine(ri.StrProp2);
            Console.WriteLine(ri.IntProp1);
            Console.WriteLine(ri.IntProp2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> test1
>
> test2
>
> 1
>
> 2

Comment: why do I need to use Reflection when I can directly do `ri.StrProp1 = "test1";` may be I'm missing some context here!!

Comment: i want the other way around... given a object, extract a string that allows me to refill it

Comment: @Leonardo I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking I guess. Show some "fake" code that demonstrates what you're trying to do maybe?

Comment: @Jakotheshadows pls check the Edit 1

Comment: It looks to me like you just want to override the ToString method. I'm afraid you're going to have to elaborate further than you have.